# JQuery Form Submission not Storing Value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a custom method for validating the user input, but my form doesn't seem to be submitting. Also, the URL changes after my first submission, and the jquery only runs once the URL's changed.

The purpose of this code is to check if the information submitted is in a database. The function runs, but the value for the name field doesn't seem to be stored upon submission, and so I keep getting the error for name.

Here's my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Smiles Galore (SG)</title>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#target').on('submit', function(){
                var emailChecker = $('#email').val();
                var idChecker = $('#number').val();
                var passCheck = $('#pwd').val();
                var userName = $('#text').val;
                if (userName.length <2){
                    alert("Please enter a name");
                }
                else{   
                    if (idChecker.toString().length != 8){
                        alert("That's not a proper input for ID. Please provide a proper ID");
                    }
                    else{
                        if (!hasUpperCase(passCheck)){
                            alert("That's not a password. Enter a proper password.");
                        }
                        else if(!/[0-9]/.test(passCheck)){
                            alert("That's not a password. Enter a proper password.");
                        }
                        else if(passCheck.length > 8){
                            alert("That's not a password. Enter a proper password.");
                        }
                        else{
                            Verification(userName,emailChecker,passCheck,idChecker);
                        }
                    }
                }
        function hasUpperCase(word){
            return word.toLowerCase()!=word;
        }

        function Verification(userName1,emailCheck1,passChecker,idCheck){
            var selection = $("list").val();
            alert("Hello");
            $.post('Access.php',{'Patron Email Address':emailCheck1,'Patron Name':userName1,'Patron ID':idCheck,'Patron Password':passChecker},function(data){
                if (data=='0'){
                    alert("The email is incorrect");
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    alert("You good");
                    if (selection == "Search for Appointment"){
                        $.post('Process.php',{'Patron Email Address':emailCheck1},function(){});
                    }
                    else if (selection == "Schedule an Appointment"){
                    return;
                    }
                    else if (selection == "Cancel an Appointment"){
                    return;
                    }
                    else if (selection == "Create/Register an Account"){
                    return;
                    }
                    return; 
                }
            }); 
        }
        return false;
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="target">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="number">ID:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number">
        </div><br>
        <label for="list">Select an Option:</label><br>
        <select name="Select an Option:" id="list">
            <option value="Schedule an Appointment">Schedule an Appointment</option>
            <option value="Cancel an Appointment">Cancel an Appointment</option>
            <option value="Search for Appointment">Search for Appointment(s)</option>
            <option value="Create/Register an Account">Create/Register an Account</option>
        </select><br>
        <br><div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" value="Continue">
        </div>
        </form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a () after `val` for name like you do on the other variables.

Change `var userName = $('#text').val;` to `var userName = $('#text').val();`

That will fix your name problem.

Also noticed that you don't have a `#` in your jquery selector for `selection`.

Change `var selection = $("list").val();` to `var selection = $("#list").val();`

Comment: I seem to be having another problem where the post statement doesn't even work. I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: @InDoingIt Did my change fix the name issue for you?

Comment: Yes, my whole Validation function works. My new issue seems to be with the post. It doesn't even work. I wrote in an alert write after the function of my first post, and it's not working.

Comment: @InDoingIt Ok since that is a new problem, it needs to be a new question. If I solved your original problem, could you upvote and mark it as the accepted answer so that this question can be resolved. Then ask a new question about the post method not working, I will be glad to help you on that as well. Just post a new question and resolve this one.